# How to make jQuery UI accordion toggle

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Accordions themselves are easy enough to toggle, I had to go with jQuery's UI accordion because of the ease of incorporating bookmarkable links. At this  point I can either get an accordion effect (from scratch) to toggle with no bookmarkable links, or get the bookmarkable links with the UI and no toggling. I'd like to be able to collapse all accordion content, that is if you click the trigger once it expands - the second click would close it. Here is what I have:

```
$(function() {
    //basic accordion settings
    $('#accWrap').accordion({
        active: false,
        alwaysOpen: false,
        autoHeight: false,
        navigation: true,
        collapsable: true,
        header: '.accButton'
    });

    //attempt at toggling - does not work correctly
    //$('.accButton').click(function() {
    //$(this).next().toggle();
    //return false;
    //}).next().hide();

    //bookmarkable function
    $(".accButton").click(function(event){
      window.location.hash=this.hash;
    });
});
```

Anyone see anything obviously wrong or a way I can incorporate the toggle functionality? As always, I appreciate the help!

thx

Comment: Are you saying that you want to be able to have multiple sections expanded at the same time?

Comment: No, I want to be able to toggle the content areas, that is if you click "headerA" once, its content is shown. Click "headerA" again and it closes the content. I have it set so that it doesn't have to have one open, but I'd like to be able to double click(?) the header and have it close.

Answer (score 8):

That's an old topic but since I was looking for the answer myself and found it in the [jQuery UI accordion doc](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#collapsible):

```
 <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#accWrap" ).accordion({
            collapsible: true
        });
    });
 </script>
```

"collapsible" is misspelled in your code, it's missing the "i".

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm not sure if this is what your trying to achieve. But this is what I use..

is't snatched from [here](http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/03/expandable-collapsible-toggle-pane-jquery.html)

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
  //hide the all of the element with class msg_body
  $(".msg_body").hide();
  //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
  $(".hidebox_head").click(function()
  {
    $(this).next(".msg_body").slideToggle(600);
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="msg_head">
click me</div>
<div class="msg_body">
alksdjf löaskdjf ölaskjdöflkjas dlfkj asödlk
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: easy enough, but I need the bookmarkable hash function, which is why I went with the UI. As I said the toggle function apart from bookmarkable/hash is easy enough, its combining them thats giving me issue. thx man.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you misspelled "collapsable".  Try spelling it "collapsible" with an "i".